# firestore query snapshot reads more than once

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a server-side nodejs program which monitors/"listens" to a particular firestore location.

```
db.collection('temp').where('processed', '==', 'false').onSnapshot(snapshots =>
{
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot =>
    {
        //processes some logic
        //db.collection('temp').document(snapshot.id).update('processed': true);
    }        
}
```

There are no issues if the query snapshot returns only one snapshot, but if the query snapshot returns more than one snapshot, the logic will be called more times than its intended. For example, if concurrently write n times to the monitored location, the logic is called n^2 times. This will incur costs towards read quotas. How can I make sure that it's only being read once per document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looping over `snapshot` in your `onSnapshot()` callback you are handling all documents that match the query each time that something changes.

If you only want to handle the documents that were changed, you'll want to [loop over `snapshot.documentChanges` as shown in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).

If you're always writing documents with `processed = false`, then you can just handle `change.type = added`:

```
db.collection('temp').where('processed', '==', 'false').onSnapshot(snapshots =>
    snapshots.docChanges.forEach(function(change) {
        if (change.type === "added") {
          //processes some logic
          //db.collection('temp').document(change.id).update('processed': true);
        }
```